# How can I make a scene switcher in Python Pygame when mouse is clicked?

Tags: python, pygame

This is my python code, using pygame. When I pressed my mouse down, scene 1 does not switch to scene 2. I am coming from Code HS, so the scene switch is from the Tell A Story project. I realized that code is not the same as pygame's. So I used pygame docs and see what I can learn from that, but nothing still. Please can any one help me. Thank you.

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()


win = pg.display.set_mode((500,500))

pg.display.set_caption('Scene Switcher')

center_x = 250 - 130
center_y = 250  

black= (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

def ct(font, size, text, color):
    mf = pg.font.Font(font, size)

    t = mf.render(text, True, color)

    return t 



def draw_scene1():
    print("This is Scene 1")
    txt = ct("SB.ttf", 40, "Hello World!", black)
    win.blit(txt, (center_x,center_y))


def draw_scene2():
    print("This is scene 2")
    txt2 = ct("SB.ttf", 40, "scene2 ", black)
    win.blit(txt2, (center_x,center_y))






while True:
    win.fill(red)

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()

            quit()
        
    mouses =  pg.mouse.get_pressed()
 

    scene_counter = 0

    # When this function is called the next scene is drawn.

    def draw_next_screen():
        global scene_counter
        scene_counter += 1
        if scene_counter == 1:
            draw_scene1()
        else:
            draw_scene2()


    if mouses:
        draw_next_screen()
    
    pg.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize `scene_counter` **before** the application loop rather than **in** the application loop.

The [`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) returns a list of Boolean values ​​that represent the state (`True` or `False`) of all mouse buttons. The state of a button is `True` as long as a button is held down. Therefor the `scene_counter` is continuously incremented in each frame as long a mouse button is hold down.

The `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs once when you click the mouse button and the `MOUSEBUTTONUP` event occurs once when the mouse button is released. Increment the counter when the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs:

```py
scene_counter = 0

run = True
while run:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            scene_counter += 1

    win.fill(red)
    if scene_counter == 0:
        draw_scene1()
    else:
        draw_scene2()

    pg.display.update()

pg.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @CanadianGamer Thank you. You're welcome.